# Reveal / know / get the sending page using request or session in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I have jsp page (say, `source.jsp`) with form:

```
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <form action="Servlet123" method="POST">
        // form fileds ... 
    </form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

And the required `doPost` in servlet -

```
@WebServlet("/Servlet123")
public class Servlet123 extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

          //use with requset...
    }
}
```

How can I get the page (in this case - `source.jsp`) sending the request to this servlet?  Is there a method in request/session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use passing parameter in a request through a hidden field:

In your jsp page:

```
<form action="Servlet123" method="post">        
   <input type="hidden" name="namePage" value="sourcePage" />
</form>
```

In your servlet:

```
String namePage = request.getParameter("namePage");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

But  read  [Alternative to "Referer" Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546097/alternative-to-referer-header)
(especially BalusC's answer).