# get request url in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, request

Suppose if I have two jsp pages *Page1.jsp* and *Page2.jsp*. And if I call *Page2.jsp* from *Page1.jsp*.

How to determine in *Page2.jsp* that this request has come from *Page1.jsp*?

I tried using following code in *Page2.jsp*

```
request.getRequestURL()
```

But it gives me *URL* of *Page2.jsp*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a header with name `referer`

```
request.getHeader( "Referer" );
```

Unlike many other header information, it is not a mandatory header field. Many a times you may not find this header in the request. To overcome that, you need to implement an alternative solution like passing a *`from`* request parameter to hold that URI of the `page1`.

Please refer to an answer on this type of [alternate solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3547220/767881).

Answer (score 1):

```
 <% out.println ( "you came from: " + request.getHeader("Referer") ); %>
```

Comment: It is the same answer given by [Ravinder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136885/1031945) 3 mins before. One thing do not use scriptlets in JSP. see [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1031945)