# How to find my website URL comes from source(reference)?

Tags: php, web

i have a website ,i promoted it by sharing it's link on facebook and Google +.
i want to know whether the visitor come from by clicking the link i share on facebook or from Google + or from google search etc.
i don't have any official deal with both facebook and Google+ for promoting my website.

> my question is! is it possible by any way ?

Comment: There is the HTTP_REFERER which is not always set by the user agent. You can check `if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']))` if something is set

Comment: I think this will help $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: yah but this is not always set by the user agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the http referer (`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`) won't be set consistently and there will be the support of `rel=noreferrer` attributes on anchors soon, this could be tricky.

But since you are the one to share the links on social media, you could add a get parameter like:

```
myFancyDomain.com?referrer=facebook
```

This is the only consistent way I could imagine :)

I guess this is a good quote (even it's kinda old):

> The "Referer" header entry is optional. You cannot rely on it being
>   present. There is no cross-browser way to get the previous link
>   because this depends on the user settings and proxy configuration
>   (i.e. what the system administrators think they should allow you to
>   see).
>
> You must find a way to live without this information.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3546124/4382892)

Comment: and what about google searches ,sometime website are search in google

Comment: There you can only check for the HTTP_REFERER